# Create a 2D array from 2x1D arrays

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I would like to create a 2D array called " `prior_total` " from 2 1D arrays " `prior_fish` " and `np.arange(5)` : the first index `i` in `prior_total[i,j]` would correspond to the `i-th element` of `prior_fish` and the second one `j` to the `j-th` element of `np.arange(5)`.

**Caution : the first array contains different number of elements than the second array.**

I tried to do like this :

```
# Declare prior array
prior_fish = np.zeros(num_prior_loop)
prior_start = 1
prior_end = 5
prior_fish = np.logspace(prior_start,prior_end,num_prior_loop)
# Prior total
prior_total = np.array((prior_fish.T, np.arange(5)))
```

But after in the code, I call :

```
prior_total[i,j] = FISH_super_flat_GCsp[7+j,7+j] + prior_fish[i]
IndexError: too many indices for array
```

What might be wrong here?

### Update

Here is the error message with @Valentin suggestion :

```
prior_fish =  [1.00000000e+01 1.20679264e+01 1.45634848e+01 1.75751062e+01
 2.12095089e+01 2.55954792e+01 3.08884360e+01 3.72759372e+01
 4.49843267e+01 5.42867544e+01 6.55128557e+01 7.90604321e+01
 9.54095476e+01 1.15139540e+02 1.38949549e+02 1.67683294e+02
 2.02358965e+02 2.44205309e+02 2.94705170e+02 3.55648031e+02
 4.29193426e+02 5.17947468e+02 6.25055193e+02 7.54312006e+02
 9.10298178e+02 1.09854114e+03 1.32571137e+03 1.59985872e+03
 1.93069773e+03 2.32995181e+03 2.81176870e+03 3.39322177e+03
 4.09491506e+03 4.94171336e+03 5.96362332e+03 7.19685673e+03
 8.68511374e+03 1.04811313e+04 1.26485522e+04 1.52641797e+04
 1.84206997e+04 2.22299648e+04 2.68269580e+04 3.23745754e+04
 3.90693994e+04 4.71486636e+04 5.68986603e+04 6.86648845e+04
 8.28642773e+04 1.00000000e+05]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "final_Jacobian_WITH_PRIOR_ONLY_on_SUPER_FISH_GCsp_dev_into_GCsp_plus_3x2pt_dev.py", line 119, in <module>
    np.stack([prior_fish.T, np.arange(5)])
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 6, in stack
  File "/opt/intel/intelpython3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/shape_base.py", line 426, in stack
    raise ValueError('all input arrays must have the same shape')
ValueError: all input arrays must have the same shape
```

Comment: check, `np.stack` and its variants...

Comment: I think you want `prior_total[[[0,i],[1,j]]]` for some `i,j`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `num_prior_loop` replaced by `5`:

```
In [26]: prior_fish = np.zeros(5)    # We don't declare arrays in Python
    ...: prior_start = 1
    ...: prior_end = 5
    ...: prior_fish = np.logspace(prior_start,prior_end,5)
```

The new array works:

```
In [27]: prior_total = np.array((prior_fish.T, np.arange(5)))
In [28]: prior_total
Out[28]: 
array([[1.e+01, 1.e+02, 1.e+03, 1.e+04, 1.e+05],
       [0.e+00, 1.e+00, 2.e+00, 3.e+00, 4.e+00]])
```

But let's change `num_prior_loop` to 7:

```
In [29]: prior_start = 1
    ...: prior_end = 5
    ...: prior_fish = np.logspace(prior_start,prior_end,7)
In [30]: 
In [30]: prior_total = np.array((prior_fish.T, np.arange(5)))
<ipython-input-30-03a511e70edc>:1: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray
  prior_total = np.array((prior_fish.T, np.arange(5)))
In [31]: prior_total
Out[31]: 
array([array([1.00000000e+01, 4.64158883e+01, 2.15443469e+02, 1.00000000e+03,
       4.64158883e+03, 2.15443469e+04, 1.00000000e+05]),
       array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])], dtype=object)
```

Besides the warning (from newer `numpy` versions), we get a 1d array with 2 array elements.

Since its shape is (2,), we can't use `[i,j]` indexing.

`stack` does more than warn:

```
In [32]: prior_total = np.stack((prior_fish.T, np.arange(5)))
...
ValueError: all input arrays must have the same shape
```

By the way `.T` on `prior_fish` does nothing since it is a 1d array - switching one axis around doesn't change anything.

```
In [33]: prior_fish.shape
Out[33]: (7,)
```

## edit

You can combine a (n,1) array with a (5,) with some sort of broadcasted operation:

```
In [55]: x = np.random.randint(0,10,(7,1))
In [56]: x
Out[56]: 
array([[0],
       [4],
       [4],
       [3],
       [0],
       [4],
       [5]])
In [57]: x + np.arange(5)
Out[57]: 
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
       [4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
       [3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
       [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]])
```

This can be index with `[i,j]`:

```
In [58]: _[2,3]
Out[58]: 7
```

Comment: I know what  you intend `[i,j]` to do, but it won't work if the array is not 2d.  There's a gap between what you intend, and what the code is actually doing.

Comment: Sorry, I had badly formulated my issue, you're right.

Comment: A comment in the followup question suggests you want a (50,5) or (5,50) array, with 5 copies of `prior_fish`.  As my first example shows, it is possible with `np.array` or `np.stack` to make a (2,5) array with correct inputs.  You need to be clearer about the desired result. (see my edit making a (7,5) array with addition.

Answer (score 1):

Use `np.stack`

```py
prior_total = np.stack([prior_fish.T, np.arange(5)])
```

---

`np.array` will create a 1D numpy array of objects (in your case, 1D numpy array of 1D numpy array).

`np.stack` takes numpy arrays and stack them together by adding 1 dimension.

Comment: t@ValentinVignal . Thanks for your quick answer : unfortunately, this doesn't work. You can see the error message into **UPDATE**.

Comment: Yes, both arrays have to have the same shape. In that case you can use `prior_total = np.stack([prior_fish.T, np.arange(len(prior_fish.T))])`

Comment: No, I want a " **len(prior_fish)x5** " 2D array. How could I perfom it ?

Comment: I think there might be a confusion on what you are trying to do. Do you want  `prior_total[i, j]` to return you a number ? Or do you want it to return you a tuple of numbers ?

Comment: I want a `2D array` where element indexed by `[i,j]` return a number

Comment: But how do you compute the `[i, j]` number from `a = prior_fish[i]` and `b = np.arange(5)[j]` ? Is it `a+b` or `a*b` ? Because you are asking to return only one number which depends on 2

Comment: If the 2 arrays are the same size and 1d, `np.array(...)` and `np.stack(...)` will produce the same thing.  But they differ in size, `stack` throws an error, and `np.array` a warning.

Comment: @hpaulj `[i,j]` elements returns the i-th element of prior_fish[i] for j given. Example : `prior_total[10,1]` refers to a different value from `prior_total[10,2]` etc ...

Comment: @ValentinVignal . Ok, thanks, so how to get access element, `prior_table[i,j]` like `prior_total[[[0,i],[1,j]]]` doesn't work : what is the right way to access element with `prior_total = np.stack([prior_fish.T, np.arange(5)])`  ?

Comment: @ValentinVignal . Sorry, I had badly formulated my issue.